# Reload recyclerview on fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an `fragment` with an `recyclerView`, I need to search in a `SearchView` ubicated in a fragment.
I implemented in my activity this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
  String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
  doMySearch(query);
}
```

I don't know how I refresh the `recyclerview` on fragment where is the `SearchView`.

Comment: The `Fragment` will be attached to the Hosting `Activity` meaning you can access your fragment from the container id or the `Fragment` tag (if you have given it one) using the `FragmentManager` (`getFragmentManager()` or v4 `getSupportFragmentManager()`). So it will be easy to create a method in your `Fragment` that updates your `RecyclerView` and call it directly from the Hosting `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Probably a few different ways to do this but you should be able to call method on your fragment from the activity (either using some reference to fragment you have already or perhaps looking it up like following)

```
    MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment);
    myFragment.updateResults();
```